# XSTREAM - class cast exception

Tags: java, xml, xstream

i have a problem easy to understand hard to fix (for me).

I have an XML file like this:

```
    <class name='package.AnnotatedClass2'>
      <attribute name='field1'>
        <attributes>
          <attribute name='targetField1name' />
          <attribute name='targetField2name' />
        </attributes>
      </attribute>
   </class>
```

I have another bean that contains an "attribute" tag (but not present in XML file), global node:

```
<class name="package.Example">
    <global>
        <excluded>
           <attribute name ="field3"/>
        </excluded>
    </global>
  </class>
```

XmlClass that stay for `<class>` tag

```
public class XmlClass {

    /** global configuration */
    public XmlGlobal global;
    /** list of attributes node */
    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="attribute")
    public List<XmlAttribute> attributes;
}
```

XmlGlobal that stay for `<global>` tag

```
public class XmlGlobal {
   public List<XmlTargetExcludedAttribute> excluded;
}

@XStreamAlias("attribute")
public class XmlTargetExcludedAttribute {
   /** name attribute of class node */
   @XStreamAsAttribute
   public String name;
}
```

And XmlAttribute:

```
public class XmlAttribute {

   /** list of target attributes */
    public List<XmlTargetAttribute> attributes;
}

@XStreamAlias("attribute")
public class XmlTargetAttribute {

   /** name attribute of attribute node */
   @XStreamAsAttribute
   public String name;
}
```

After perfoming the toXml() method in xmlAttribute.attributes i have two instances of XmlTargetExcludedAttribute instead of XmlTargetAttribute.

to be precise: the classes XmlTargetExcludedAttribute and XmlTargetAttribute are identical only for ease of reading, in fact they are different.

how can I explain that class to use?

Comment: Please show the actual Java code for Aelement and Belement (or at least, some code that is valid Java and demonstrates the problem).  Your current `public Anode;` is not a valid Java field declaration, but if you had `public Anode node;` (and removed the alias annotations on the node classes) then it should work as you require.

Comment: I have tested your example (correcting the compilation errors) and it works as you expected. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than aliasing the two different classes globally, you could register a local [`NamedCollectionConverter`](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/extended/NamedCollectionConverter.html) on each of the List-valued properties:

```
public class XmlGlobal {
   @XStreamConverter(value=NamedCollectionConverter.class, useImplicitType=false,
      strings={"attribute"}, types={XmlTargetExcludedAttribute.class})
   public List<XmlTargetExcludedAttribute> excluded;
}

public class XmlTargetExcludedAttribute {
   /** name attribute of class node */
   @XStreamAsAttribute
   public String name;
}


public class XmlAttribute {

   /** list of target attributes */
   @XStreamConverter(value=NamedCollectionConverter.class, useImplicitType=false,
      strings={"attribute"}, types={XmlTargetAttribute.class})
   public List<XmlTargetAttribute> attributes;
}

public class XmlTargetAttribute {

   /** name attribute of attribute node */
   @XStreamAsAttribute
   public String name;
}
```